# PHP onclick confirm to Sweet Alert 2 confirmation

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I need your help here please.I have a button which is echoed by a PHP file to a HTML file. When the button is clicked it uses window `confirm()` method but I want to use a sweet alert 2 modal to be displayed with yes or no option in the HTML file.

Does anyone have any idea how I can make this work?

PHP echo:

```
$row['handler'] = "<a class=\"btn btn-detail btn-small\" href=\"user.php?act=cancel_order&order_id=".$row['order_id'].
"\" onclick=\"if (!confirm('".$GLOBALS['_LANG']['confirm_cancel'].
"')) return false;\">".$GLOBALS['_LANG']['cancel'].
"</a>";
```

Do I need to add the script to a external file and call it inside PHP or there is better way to do this ?

Comment: read about bootstrap modal

Comment: I already have a modal working, the question is about the best possible way to call it inside the php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just modified your code.

```
$row['handler'] = '<a class="btn btn-detail btn-small" href="javascript:;" onclick="confirmation(\''.$GLOBALS['_LANG']['confirm_cancel'].
        '\',\'user.php?act=cancel_order&order_id='.$row['order_id'].
        '\')">'.$GLOBALS['_LANG']['cancel'].
    '</a>';
```

And your javascript function will looks like this

```
function confirmation(text,text2)
  {
    swal({
      title: text,
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
      cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
      confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
      cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
      buttonsStyling: false
    }).then(function () {
      location.href=text2;
    }, function (dismiss) {
        return false;
    })
  }
```

Hope it will work :)